# How to load startup file with import

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and Node.js

I have just two files package.json and server.js

I am getting the following error:

```
require() of /home/cherjh/scheckout/server.js from /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
```

It seems that lsnode in  /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js is using require() to load my application startup file “server.js”.

Does anyone know what the lsnode application is and how to make it use import to load server.js file? I am using Node.js 14.21.2.

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

My server.js file

```
import express from "express";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import cors from "cors";
import "dotenv/config";
import path from "path";
const _dirname = path.resolve();

const { CLIENT_ID, APP_SECRET } = process.env;
const app = express();
const base = "https://api-m.sandbox.cheriths.com";
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));

const generateAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
      const auth = Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET).toString("base64");
      const response = await fetch(${base}/v1/oauth2/token, {
        method: "post",
        body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
        headers: {
          Authorization: Basic ${auth},
        },
      });
    
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.access_token;
  } catch(error) {
      console.error("Failed to generate Access Token:", error);
  } 
};
```

I removed `type = modules` from package.json. I used node-fetch 2.6.12 instead of 3.3.1. I also changed all the import in server.js to require() and the error no longer displays. It is not satisfactory because I want to use import and node-fetch 3.3.1.

The error reappears when I change the require in server.js to import.

Comment: How did you reach that error? Can you share your terminal commands? There's no obvious indication in your code that lsnode is required or run. Afaik, lsnode isn't a typical command to run a node project.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.The node.js is hosted by a web hosting company. On the Node.Js interface you simply click Start to start your application startup file. 
In the terminal I opened the file   /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js . The lsnode.js file has an application startup function that starts the server.js.
function startApplication() {
if (!startupFile.startsWith('/')) {
        startupFile = appRoot + '/' + startupFile;
    }
The file uses require and not import.

Comment: I would add that the Node.js is on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Import syntax is used in ECMAScript, which has to be enabled for Node 14.21.2. According to this documentation, using `"type": "module"` in package.json causes all *.js files to be interpreted as ECMAScript, which explains your issue with lsnode.js. Try removing that field from your package.json and changing `server.js` to `server.mjs`. This should make it so only your server code is interpreted as ECMAScript, while your lsnode.js is kept as CommonJS.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system